# How to get a particular part of URL?

Tags: java, jsp, url, jakarta-ee

If my urls are as  'https://test.company.com' , 'https://hello.company.com'. I just want to fetch what is at the place of `test` or `hello` so how to get that in jsp. `request.getRequestUrl()` will give a complete url itself, but I just want to know what is at the place of `test`,`hello`.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html):

```
final URI uri = request.getURL().toURI();
final String hostname = uri.getHost();
```

Then operate on `hostname` (something like `hostname.split("\\.")[0]`, for instance).

Comment: What will be stored in hostname here?

Comment: `test.company.com`, for instance; the hostname part of the URI ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern subDomainPattern = Pattern.compile("^(.+)\\.company\\.com$");
Matcher matcher = subDomainPattern.matcher(httpServletRequest.getServerName());
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

assume you only want to get the sub domain name of company.com